# Why not just use a long TTL reference token in replace of access and refresh JWT tokens?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, single-page-application, jwt, auth0

I'm building both a mobile and single-page app and have been evaluating auth techniques that **allow for immediate access/token revocation**.  I see Auth0 and Stormpath use both access and refresh tokens in addition to allowing for revoking tokens.

What's the point of a refresh token and short TTL access token if you're maintaining a list of valid tokens and checking against that upon reach request received on the resource server?  Why not create one reference token with the same TTL as you would set on the refresh token and now you don't have to worry about refreshing the access token (right before it's about expire) and have one less token to worry about?

Answer (score 1):

Revoking refresh tokens is typically something a ***resource owner*** does when he/she thinks the token may have been compromised (phone/laptop lost for example).

Issuing a refresh token and forcing the client to refresh the short-lived access token allows the authorization server to periodically validate that the subject (logged in user) is still valid.

If you issue access tokens that are long lived, you lose the ability to revoke access for users that left the organization.

When someone leaves an organization, the admin wants to delete their account from the identity provider and be assured that they can no longer access any resources. Long lived access tokens would force an admin to also go into possibly multiple authorization servers and delete the access tokens for that user.

Comment: Checking that the subject is still valid is something that I need to be done immediately and not periodically, which is why I’m confused on the necessity of the refresh token.  If a malicious employee has their account terminated, we need their access revoked right away.  If a user logs out, that token needs to be invalid right away. Same if we detect a user’s token has been compromised.  To achieve this, several have proposed maintaining a blacklist or whitelist of tokens.  There is just one authorization server.  And all tokens would point to a user id.

Comment: Well, I can't comment on your particular requirements. Those should flow from your threat analysis. But in most situations, having short-lived tokens (say TTL=15 min) is close enough to immediate revocation. Having a single authorization server that each resource server needs to talk to for every request creates a scalability bottleneck and single point of failure in your architecture. For most organizations, that weighs heavier than having to wait 15 min to invalidate issued tokens.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make it clear, but the requirements were for the ability to immediately revoke a token.  And to do that you need to maintain a list of tokens.  And if you're already maintaining a list of tokens and checking against that, I'm confused as to why you need a refresh token and access token.

Comment: But immediate access token revocation was not a requirement for OAuth2/OIDC. If your requirements don't fit the design of the standards, you are free to develop something that fits better. Just be aware that this comes with significant downsides/risk. Access tokens that do not expire would be unacceptable in most use-cases I've worked on. If someone loses their token without detecting it, you give the attacker unlimited access.

Answer (score 1):

As of today IdentityServer provides a reference tokens feature as well as refresh/access. According to your requerements it's absolutely right to use reference tokens. This way you will be able to manage it's validity internally and immediately. As [docs](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/tokens/overview/) say:

> Reference tokens allow for immediate revocation (by deleting the token data from your IdentityServer data store), whereas a JWT can only be invalidated via expiration.

However, this solution comes with trade-offs:

`+` you have complete control over the token's validity

`+` your requests from clients are more concise

`-` some latency introduced due to the need for a database request to check the token

Comment: I hope that this answer will find its use even though the original question was asked a long time ago